# Orthogonality in inner product/Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

Given a sequence $(f_{n})$ of nonzero elements in some infinite dimensional vector space $V$, does there necessarily exist some $g\in V$ such that $\left<g,f_{n}\right>\ne 0$ for each $n=1,2,...$? If there is no such $g$, then what about if $V$ is a Hilbert space? Or even separable Hilbert space?

The way I approach it is to consider the dimension of $f_{n}^{\perp}:=\{h\in V:\left<h,f_{n}\right>=0\}$ and argue about the dimension of $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n}f_{n}^{\perp}$. There are two type of dimensions, vector space dimension and Hilbert space dimension, it is well known that the Hilbert space dimension of any separable Hilbert space is $\leq\omega$. If I want to argue in that way, it seems that I cannot rely on Hilbert space dimension, indeed, perhaps it is a very wrong that I start in that way.

Comment: Maybe I should restrict my question to Hilbert space rather than inner product space. For $V=\{(a_{1},...,a_{n},...): a_{i} \text{are all zero except finitely many}\}$, if we take $f_{n}=(0,...,1,...,0,...)$, $1$ located in $n$ coordinate, then any such $g$ has infinitely many nonzero coordinate which does not belong to $V$. And note that we can perform orthogornal process and express any vector in coordinate form.

Comment: Do you know Baire's category theorem?

Comment: Yes I do, but wait a minute, I realize that my question does not make sense even if $V$ is Hilbert space. Since we can use Zorn's Lemma to deduce that such $V$ must have a vector space basis $B$, although not necessary that of $\omega$ type, but the setting that infinite dimensional always allows us to pick up a denumerable sequence of nonzero vectors from $B$, then the same circumstances arise as what I have commented, is there anything wrong with my argument?

Comment: So the sequence $(f_{n})$ must confine to only finitely many distinct elements, that is, the range of $(f_{n})$ must be of the form $\{f_{n_{1}},...,f_{n_{m}}\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that there is no $g $ as you want it. This means for each $g \in H $, there is $n \in \Bbb {N} $ with
$$
g \in M_n =\{x \in H \,\mid\,\langle x,f_n\rangle =0\}.
$$

In other words,
$$
H =\bigcup_n M_n .
$$

It is easy to see that each $M_n $ is closed. Thus, by Baire's category theorem, some $M_n $ has nonempty interior. But $M_n $ is a subspace of $H$ and no proper subspace of a vector space can have nonempty interior. Thus, $M_n =H$, which easily implies $f_n =0$, a contradiction.

Thus, the assumption that there is no $g $ with the desired property is false.

Note that I used completeness of $H $ for the application of Baire's theorem. As you noted yourself in the comments, for incomplete spaces, the claim can fail, for example for the subspace $V \leq \ell^2 (\Bbb {N}) $ of finitely supported sequences.

Comment: Okay, but I wonder why I got such a contradictory circumstances, as what I have commented, but I would like to state it clearly: Choose a vector space basis $B$ of $V$, since $V$ is assumed infinite dimensional, we got a subset of distint elements of $B$, say, $\{k_{n}: n\in{\bf{N}}\}$, perform Gram's process to deduce such an orthonormal set $F=\{f_{n}: n\in{\bf{N}}\}$, such $f_{n}$'s are all nonzero, then $\left<g,f_{n}\right>\ne 0$ is exactly the coordinate of $g$ when represented by $F$, but this cannot happen, since vector space basis allows only finitely many nonzero components.

Comment: So I wonder is there a requirement in Baire's theorem for each $M_{n}$ to be distinct?

Comment: No, there is no such requirement. Also, there is no countable basis of an infinite dimensional Hilbert space (as can also be proved using Baire). Finally, for your orthonormal set $F$, you will find a $g \in H$ with $\langle g, f_n \rangle \neq 0$ for all $n$. This is no contradiction, all you will get is that $g \in H$ will not lie in the span of $F$ (i.e. $g$ is not a **finite** linear combination of elements of $F$). Since $\{k_n \mid n\}$ can be no basis of **all of $H$,** this is no contradiction.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Much more clearer now!!!

Comment: Thanks to your proof that it suggests also that: Given a Banach space $X$, $\{x_{n}\}\subseteq X-\{0\}$, $\{x_{n}^{*}\}\subseteq X^{*}-\{0\}$, then there exist some $x\in X$, $x^{*}\in X^{*}$ such that $\left<x_{n},x^{*}\right>\ne 0$ and also $\left<x,x_{n}^{*}\right>\ne 0$ for each $n=1,2,...$. Simply put your $M_{n}$ to be the perp in $X$, $X^{*}$ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ is a Hilbert space, then there is an orthonormal basis for it (see e.g. Bruce K Driver "Analysis Tools with Applications). The sequence's elements $f_n$ can be expressed in combinations of the basis vectors.

If the number of basis vectors involved in the sequence is finite, we can find a $g$ solving the expression.

If it is infinite, can we use that the Hilbert space is complete to prove the existence of such a $g$?

Comment: I'm sorry? For supoose $V=l^{2}$, $B=\{f_{n}\}$, where $f_{n}$ is the sequence which $i$ component is $1$ and $0$ otherwise, then $g=(1,1/2,1/3,...)$ is certainly not a zero element in $l^{2}$ with $\left<g,f_{n}\right>=1/n^{2}\ne 0$ for all $n$, so why we would have $0$ is the possibly solution?

Comment: Oh, misread the question, read an equality sign instead of a "not equal" sign.

Comment: And I have noted that it actually does not make sense in asking such a question under the merely inner product space setting.

Comment: I am interested in understanding how you show your assertion ''If the number of basis vectors involved in the sequence is finite, we can find a gg solving the expression''

Comment: Take $g=\sum \alpha_i b_i$ with suitables $\alpha$s (projection), where $b$s are the basis vector.

Comment: Okay maybe I got what you meant: For simplicity we let $f_{n}\in\text{span}\{b_{1},b_{2}\}$, where $b_{1},b_{2}$ are orthonormal, and that $b_{3}$ is orthogonal to both $b_{1},b_{2}$, then $g=b_{1}+b_{2}+b_{3}$ will serve the need.

Comment: Yes. For the infinite basis vector case I would try to prove the statement using that a Hilbert space is complete, i.e. if no such $g$ in $V$ exists then this would yield a contradiction...

Comment: actually I did make a serious mistake, anyway, your assertion is absolutely true: For that $g$ I constructed, it does not necessary fulfill the requirement, but what we can see is that, using real projective space or whatsoever, if we assume $\|f_{n}\|=1$, then there are only at most countable points in unit sphere, for then we can always choose a line through origin that intersects no any points $f_{n}$, for the normal line to that line, it is the $g$ that we required.